# How can i see custom bookmark in electron.dialog.showOpenDialog with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, dialog, electron

Problem: I need to choose folder from server-folder but I can't see it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, your question, as it is, contains not enough information to understand your problem. Think of a neighbour coming to you saying that his car does not work, because he does not find a button on his custom built in satnav. But you have never seen his car. It is hard to help him or even understand what is wrong, right? So try to see it from this angle and look into the link in @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp comment. Create a simple main.js that calls only the dialog function after checking that electron.app is ready (which the function requires). Modify it until you can reproduce your error and post this code.

Comment: (By editing it into your question) Complete also means, that your error is hard to understand, if whe don't know what kind of files you are trying to see or open.